# how to set condition in jenkins job via shell script

Tags: jenkins

I want to use the "conditional step (single)" with Run? parameter as "Execute shell".

I can't find what script need return or define in order to set condition true or false.

The builder step never trigger.

Answer (score 1):

This is managed with exit codes.
If you wish to return false condition, you need to return a non-zero exit code (e.g. 'exit 1').
If you wish to return true condition, you need to return successful exit code (e.g. 'exit 0').